# Intro to web design - adding href to images messes up my layout

Tags: html, css, layout, href, anchor

this is my first question on here so forgive me if I'm doing anything wrong.

I'm trying to add a-href links to my images however, when I do it, it messes up my entire layout. What I'm trying to do is have one larger, "main_image", and the "support_images" wrapped next it. "main_image" and "support_images" are separate divs both inside a bigger div: "section_container".

I thought that if I just changed my css to target "a" instead of "img" it would be fine. But it's not :( I've also tried re-working my css to work around the problem - changing widths and heights but there seems to be something that I'm missing because its very unresponsive. I even tried putting my entire "main_image" in its own div.

I didn't think adding links to images would affect the layout. Any help is good. Thank you.

[What it's suppose to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Pc5.png)
[What happened after I added a-href links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMCDR.jpg)

HTML:

```
    <section class="section_container">
      <h2>About</h2>
      <hr><br>
      <div class="container_images">
          <a class="main_image" href="pages/about.html#gassho-houses">
          <img src="img/home/about/gassho_houses.png" alt="A Gassho home" /></a>
        <div class="support_images">
          <a href="pages/about.html#history-and-trade">
            <img src="img/home/about/history_and_trade.png" alt="3 Gassho style houses lined up" />
          </a>
          <a href="pages/about.html#location-and-transport">
            <img src="img/home/about/location_and_transport.png" alt="bus at a bus stop" />
          </a>
          <a href="pages/about.html#weather">
            <img src="img/home/about/community.png" alt="a local man" />
          </a>
          <a href="pages/about.html#community">
            <img src="img/home/about/weather.png" alt="Gassho home covered in snow" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
    .section_container {
      background-color: #e0e0e0;
      color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
      width: 50%;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    .container_images {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      align-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .container_images .main_image {
      width: 40%;
    }
    
    .support_images {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .support_images a img {
      margin-bottom: 3.85%;
      width: 45%;
    }
```

Comment: For one, you don't have the main image in its own div, as you described. Also, in your image "What it's suppose to look like," it looks like everything spans the whole width, but your section's width is 50%.